# Как запустить .py через .bat с параметром?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bat

[image: ztho]

Допустим,я хочу запустить файл manage.py через .bat-файл,но мне нужно его запустить с параметром 'db init'? 
Как я могу это сделать?
Спасибо)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`python manage.py db init`

Работает?)

Comment: Не думал,что все так просто,спасибо!